# how to compare differences between conditions with respect to a specific trend effect?

Tags: r, mixed-model, trend

I'm trying to compute a statistic that will allow me to test for differences between conditions regarding a particular trend:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=rep(seq(1,6),each=24), x=rep(seq(1,12),times=6), w = rep(c("A","B"),each=12,times=6), y=c(2,3,1,5,3,2,5,6,3,5,3,4,18,18,19,17,14,11,6,3,7,4,3,2, 3,4,2,2,2,1,7,5,1,3,5,6,14,15,12,12,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,2, 5,4,4,7,5,3,2,2,3,5,1,3,16,14,13,12,6,6,3,3,4,5,2,2, 6,5,6,4,5,8,6,7,3,5,7,5,18,15,16,11,11,12,4,4,5,3,1,1, 2,2,1,5,4,2,5,5,3,5,3,1,20,11,10,9,2,11,2,2,3,4,5,1, 1,1,1,3,3,1,4,1,4,5,1,4,10,15,10,11,11,12,12,6,4,3,2,1))
```

My first thought was to simply compute a t-statistic for each combination of `x` and `w`:
`A1 vs B1`, `A2 vs B2`, etc...

But is there a better way to determine whether a specific trend for `B` is significantly different than that for `A`? For example, in my example data, I expect condition `B` to start high and gradually decline to baseline, whereas condition `A` will remain at baseline (as suggested by `qplot(x,y,color=w, data=data)`).

I can get the significance of the interaction with:

```
anova(lmer(y ~ x*w + (1|ID), data=data))
```

But don't know how to get R to compute differences between conditions with respect to a specific trend effect.

Comment: Did you check the `emmeans` package ?

Comment: Thanks @RobertLong. Yes, I did, `emmeans` is what I use to compare A1 vs B1, A2 vs B2 etc. But how do I test for a difference between conditions with respect to the trend I'm expecting above? I suspect I'll need a custom contrast, but this is what I don't know how to set up.

Comment: "difference between conditions with respect to the trend" - that's the interaction estimates